# Count occurrences starting with a specific number (Benford's Law)

Tags: excel, statistics, excel-formula, countif, array-formulas

I have a table in Excel with all the countries and associated population counts. I would like to count how many times the number starts by 1, then 2, ... 9. It's about [Benford's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law), for school homework.

I tried with NB.SI or COUNTIF but they didn't work. I even tried to convert numbers into text but NB.SI didn't work any better.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try the `LEFT` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,1)
```

and copy down.  Then in **C1** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(B$1:B$20,ROW())
```

and copy down through **C9**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With creation of a suitable bins array (say C1:C10) can be achieved with a single formula. Select D1:D10, enter:

```
=FREQUENCY(A1:A20,C1:C10)
```

in formula bar and confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without adding another column and without using an array formula.

To get the of numbers in the sequence that start with 1, use this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(populationcounts,">=1000",populationcounts,"<2000")
```

For numbers that start with 2, adjust the criteria:

```
=COUNTIFS(populationcounts,">=2000",populationcounts,"<3000")
```

and so on.

[image: Countif number left 1]